# Django cookie age not setting

Tags: django, angularjs, cookies

I am trying to create a way for my users to have a "remember me" option when they log in. However as it stands, no matter what I try, when I view the cookie in my browser, it just shows `Expires: At end of session`. So once I close my browser and come back to my page, I am logged out.

In my settings.py I have set

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 10000000
```

Which I assume are what I need to do...

On the front-end (which is in AngularJS) I have the following for the cookie storage:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/login/', {email: this.login['arguments'][0]['email'], password: this.login['arguments'][0]['password']})
        .success(function(response){
          if (response.token){
            $cookieStore.put('djangotoken', response.token);
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + response.token;
          }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
          $cookieStore.remove('djangotoken');
        });
```

If someone could show me how to get my cookies to just stay for the designated age I set that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the cookie directly from Angular, so it has nothing to do with the Django session cookie age. You need to pass the expiration time when you set the cookie.

Unfortunately, the built-in Angular cookieStore api is unnecessarily restrictive and does not support this. It looks like a good alternative is [angular-cookie](https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie).

Comment: My project is still in its early stages, so I'm not locked into what I'm doing - would you suggest I somehow set the cookie from Django instead?

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. Django is already storing logged-in status in the session. If you are simply trying to determine whether the user is logged in or not, you should pass that from Django - perhaps in the context when you render the base template.